# JavaScript not executing inside xul file

Tags: javascript, xul

I am having trouble writing js in a XUL file. I have written a simple method inside xul but it doesn't execute when you open the browser.

This is the method inside the xul tag:

```
function demo() {
    alert('hello');
}
```

I ve tried to change the tag of the script from `<script>` to `<html:script>` but still method doesn't work. I tried to use methods from external js file using `<html:script type="application/x-javascript" src="overlay.js">` still not working.

The name of the xul file is `ff-sidebar.xul`. Basically what I am trying to do is display text on the sidebar using javascript functions that are in external js files. I really need javascript to work inside xul file so I can use the js methods. I know for sure that nothing is wrong with the js file.

Comment: I ve seen the examples online no eval is used. I think I am doing something wrong here I don't know what.

Comment: Your question doesn't provide enough information. This might be because you forgot (like I always do) that you need to quote `<>`s. But at a minimum it would help to know how you are loading the XUL file.

Comment: Indent code by 4 spaces. This will format the code so that it's easier to read. (You can also do this by selecting some text and then pressing the {} (curly braces) button when editing.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an addressing problem in your JavaScript reference. I believe Firefox is not able to locate overlay.js. Try this:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="chrome://sidebar/content/overlay.js">
```

where "sidebar" is the name of your app, and your .js file is located in the "sidebar/chrome/content" directory, alongside your sidebar.xul file.

More information on the chrome URL can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/The_Chrome_URL).